# How photon beam can be attained through Proton Accelerator?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, protons, nuclear-engineering, photon-emission

I'm recently had been reading quite a lot about ADS and transmutation possiblity of Proton beam to neutralize nuclear waste. I came across with an Article from Big THINK https://bigthink.com/the-present/laser-nuclear-waste/

I was thinking, How one might can attain Photon beam by using a proton accelerator with a beam rate of 1000 MeV. Followed by that, If anyone can explain to me, Whether, Spallation will occur if photons are used in-place or neutrons or some other phenomenon might take place we photons are used.

**Note:** I'm a high school senior. I don't know much about Particle Physics but I do read interesting researcher papers on it and try to understand about it! Apologises if its pretty basic question for the platform.

Comment: Uhmm! It was for a Physics Competition and they only give us a proton beam. So, I want to do an experiment with photon beam. If problem occurs then I can tackle them with math or citing limitations. But, I don't know perfectly how photon can be attained from a proton beam? Can you help me with this?

Comment: @annav an undulator is used to obtain coherent synchrotron radiation from a charged particle beam, though using a proton beam greatly reduces the intensity of said beam. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undulator

Comment: @Triatticus I can use electron or antiprotons too! Can they do advantage than the proton beam?

Comment: @Triatticus thanks, I will edit

Comment: The simplest way to get a photon beam is with a laser,accelerator.  link:  accelconf.web.cern.ch/e06/PAPERS/TUOAFI03.PDF,  one cannot get a coherent photon beam with only a proton beam , extra insturmentation is needed as in the link by triatticus.

Comment: Voting to close as homework question as per the OP's comment